# How do I get the first day of the week of a date in mysql?

Tags: mysql, date, select, time

Suppose I have 2011-01-03 and I want to get the first of the week, which is sunday, which is 2011-01-02, how do I go about doing that?

The reason is I have this query:

```
select 
  YEAR(date_entered) as year, 
  date(date_entered) as week,   <-------This is what I want to change to select the first day of the week.
  SUM(1) as total_ncrs, 
  SUM(case when orgin = picked_up_at then 1 else 0 end) as ncrs_caught_at_station 
from sugarcrm2.ncr_ncr 
where 
sugarcrm2.ncr_ncr.date_entered > date('2011-01-01') 
and orgin in( 
'Silkscreen', 
'Brake', 
'Assembly', 
'Welding', 
'Machining', 
'2000W Laser', 
'Paint Booth 1', 
'Paint Prep', 
'Packaging', 
'PEM', 
'Deburr', 
'Laser ', 
'Paint Booth 2', 
'Toolpath' 
) 
and date_entered is not null 
and orgin is not null 
AND(grading = 'Minor' or grading = 'Major') 
 and week(date_entered) > week(current_timestamp) -20 
group by year, week(date_entered) 
order by year   asc, week asc
```

And yes, I realize that origin is spelled wrong but it was here before I was so I can't correct it as too many internal apps reference it.

So, I am grouping by weeks but I want this to populate my chart, so I can't have all the beginning of weeks looking like different dates. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you need to handle weeks which start on Mondays, you could also do it that way. First define a custom `FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK` function:

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE FUNCTION FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK(day DATE)
RETURNS DATE DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  RETURN SUBDATE(day, WEEKDAY(day));
END;;
DELIMITER ;
```

And then you could do:

```
SELECT FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK('2011-01-03');
```

For your information, MySQL provides two different functions to retrieve the first day of a week. There is [DAYOFWEEK](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek):

> Returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 = Saturday). These index values correspond to the ODBC standard.

And [WEEKDAY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday):

> Returns the weekday index for date (0 = Monday, 1 = Tuesday, … 6 = Sunday).

Comment: This is almost working for me. I would like to get the date for Sunday as that is the first day I am going by for the week. So if I pass in '2017-06-24' (Saturday), FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK is returning '2017-06-19' (Monday). How do I get it to return '2017-06-18' (Sunday)?

Comment: @JasonAyer If you haven't managed to make it work yet, you can do `RETURN SUBDATE(day, DAYOFWEEK(day) - 1);` inside the function instead.

Answer (score 118):

If the week starts on Sunday do this:

```
DATE_ADD(mydate, INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK(mydate)) DAY)
```

If the week starts on Monday do this:

```
DATE_ADD(mydate, INTERVAL(-WEEKDAY(mydate)) DAY);
```

[more info](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2006/09/22/mysql-find-week-startend-based-on-week-number/)

Comment: Here it starts on Sundays, in Canada, in this building.

Comment: Yup, but we're a company in Canada, who's pay period starts on Sunday, and it's an internal report that is to rank employees for pay periods, so Europe's first day being Monday is redundant. It is, however, very cool trivia!

Comment: Also, Britain sees Sunday as the first day of the week as well, so it's not all of Europe.

Comment: no it doesn't. i'm in UK and the week starts here on [Monday](http://www.npl.co.uk/reference/faqs/which-is-the-first-day-of-the-week-and-which-is-week-1-of-the-year-(faq-time)) :)

Comment: I just googled, to be honest. But that's cool. But my solution is in canada for canada

Comment: The solution for week beginning on a Monday didn't work for me. For example, you'd expect SELECT DATE_ADD('2015-08-30', INTERVAL(1-DAYOFWEEK('2015-08-30')) +1 DAY); (which is a Sunday) to return the previous Monday (Aug 24th) but it doesn't. Instead, I found SELECT DATE_ADD('2015-08-30', INTERVAL(-WEEKDAY('2015-08-30')) DAY); worked.

Comment: In case anyone needs the last day of a week, here it is `DATE_ADD(mydate, INTERVAL(6 -WEEKDAY(mydate)) DAY)`

Answer (score 17):

If week starts on Monday

```
  SELECT SUBDATE(mydate, weekday(mydate));
```

If week starts on Sunday

```
  SELECT SUBDATE(mydate, dayofweek(mydate) - 1);
```

**Example:**

```
SELECT SUBDATE('2018-04-11', weekday('2018-04-11'));
```

2018-04-09

```
SELECT SUBDATE('2018-04-11', dayofweek('2018-04-11') - 1);
```

2018-04-08

Answer (score 13):

Week starts  day from sunday then get First date  of the Week and Last date  of week

```
SELECT  
  DATE("2019-03-31" + INTERVAL (1 - DAYOFWEEK("2019-03-31")) DAY) as start_date,  
  DATE("2019-03-31" + INTERVAL (7 - DAYOFWEEK("2019-03-31")) DAY) as end_date
```

Week starts  day from Monday then get First date of the Week and Last date  of week

```
SELECT  
  DATE("2019-03-31" + INTERVAL ( - WEEKDAY("2019-03-31")) DAY) as start_date, 
  DATE("2019-03-31" + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY("2019-03-31")) DAY) as end_date
```

Answer (score 8):

```
select '2011-01-03' - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY('2011-01-03')+1) DAY;
```

returns the date of the first day of week. You may look into it.

Comment: If the date input in this is a Sunday already, it rolls it back 1 week instead of leaving it as that Sunday.

Answer (score 2):

This is a much simpler approach than writing a function to determine the first day of a week.

Some variants would be such as 
`SELECT DATE_ADD((SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())+1)DAY),INTERVAL 7 DAY)` (for the ending date of a query, such as between "beginning date" and "ending date"). 
`SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())+1) DAY` (for the beginning date of a query).

This will return all values for the current week.  An example query would be as follows:
`SELECT b.foo FROM bar b`
`WHERE b.datefield BETWEEN`
`(SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())+1) DAY)`
 
   `AND` 
 `(SELECT DATE_ADD((SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())+1)DAY),INTERVAL 7 DAY))`

Answer (score 1):

This works form me

Just make sure both dates in the below query are the same...

```
SELECT ('2017-10-07' - INTERVAL WEEKDAY('2017-10-07') Day) As `mondaythisweek`
```

This query returns: 2017-10-02 which is a monday,

But if your first day is sunday, then just subtract a day from the result of this and wallah!

Answer (score 0):

If the week starts on Monday do this:

```
DATE_SUB(mydate, INTERVAL WEEKDAY(mydate) DAY)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
  SELECT MIN(DATE*given_date*) FROM *table_name*
```

This will return when the week started at for any given date.

Keep the good work going!