# How to display Records From a given date range?

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to search date wise data from a specific date range by using Cakephp.I am putting two dates on two search box like **2014-05-01 to** **2014-05-31**

My table is something like below :

```
===================================
   id  |      date     |   amount
===================================
   1   |   2014-05-04  |   200
===================================
   2   |   2014-05-05  |   100
===================================
   3   |   2014-05-06  |   100
===================================
   4   |   2014-05-07  |   200
===================================
   5   |   2014-05-08  |   100
===================================
   6   |   2014-05-09  |   100
===================================
   4   |   2014-05-10  |   200
===================================
   5   |   2014-05-11  |   100
===================================
   6   |   2014-05-09  |   100
===================================
   7   |   2014-05-10  |   200
===================================
   8   |   2014-05-11  |   100
===================================
   9   |   2014-05-12  |   100
===================================
   10  |   2014-05-13 |   200
===================================
   11  |   2014-05-14 |   100
===================================
   12  |   2014-05-15 |   100
```

After my searching with respect to two dates, I want my output by week which will start from sunday.I am giving the required output below :

```
=============================
     Date   |    Amount
=============================
2014-05-04  |   1000
=============================
2014-05-11  |   600
============================= 
2014-05-18  |   0
============================= 
2014-05-25  |   0
=============================
```

I tried the code below which is not the solution :

```
$weeklyData = $this->Order->find('all', array(
            'fields' => array('SUM(Order.price) as price,WEEK(Booking.arrival_date) week ,Booking.club_id'),
            'conditions' => array('Booking.club_id' => $club_info['Club']['id'], 'Booking.arrival_date >=' => '2014-05-01', 'Booking.arrival_date <=' => '2014-05-31'),
            'group' => 'Booking.arrival_date'));
```

I.E I want whole month value and also sum of every week by this month. Any idea will help me lot. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should use [`WEEK(date\[,mode\])`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week) method get week number, then using `group by weeknumber` clause.

Possible solution:

```
select first_day_of_week(Booking.arrival_date), sum(order.price) 
from tables 
group by week(Booking.arrival_date)
```

first_day_of_week implement [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11229880/1367519)

Comment: Can you please write the full query?

Comment: @Vibration is it useful?