# Get first day of week - SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the week number and year inside a two variables ($week and $year), and I want to know what is the first day (Monday) of that week, of that year.
For example, the value of my variable ($week) is 30 (ie week 30) and the $year is 2017 (year 2017), I want it to return the first day of week 30 of 2017, which is July 24

How do I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have year value?

Comment: I think you're going to need the full date, including year.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the first day of the week of a date in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944055/how-do-i-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-of-a-date-in-mysql)

Comment: Yes, I also have the year inside a variable ($year)

Comment: this reads more like a php question... $week and $year are not typical sql variables. Please update your question with the code you have so far, and how your database is set up.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @Year int,@Week int,@YearText varchar(4)

set @Year = 2017
set @Week = 10

set @YearText = @Year

print dateadd(day,1 - datepart(dw, @YearText + '-01-01')+ (@Week-1) * 7,@YearText + '-01-01')
```