# MySQL Get Orders From Last 12 Weeks Monday to Sunday

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores each order made by a user, recording the date it was made , the amount and the user id. I am trying to create a query that returns the weekly transactions from Monday to Sunday for the last 12 weeks for a particular user. I am using the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Orders, 
SUM(amount) AS Total, 
DATE_FORMAT(transaction_date,'%m/%Y') AS Week
FROM shop_orders
WHERE user_id = 123 
AND transaction_date >= now()-interval 3 month
GROUP BY YEAR(transaction_date), WEEKOFYEAR(transaction_date)  
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(transaction_date,'%m/%Y') ASC
```

This produces the following result:

[image: Screenshot]

This however does not return the weeks where the user has made 0 orders, does not sum the orders from Monday to Sunday and does not return the weeks ordered from 1 to 12. Is there a way to achieve these things?

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) - That said, I think you should handle issues of data display in application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is with an self outer join (in this case, I use a right outer join, but of course a left outer join would work as well).

To start your weeks on Monday, subtract the result of `WEEKDAY` from your column `transaction_date` with `DATE_SUB`, as proposed in the most upvoted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944055/how-do-i-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-of-a-date-in-mysql).

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(t1.Orders, 0) AS `Orders`,
    COALESCE(t1.Total, 0) AS `Total`,
    t2.Week AS `Week`
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        COUNT(*) AS `Orders`, 
        SUM(amount) AS `Total`, 
        DATE(DATE_SUB(transaction_date, INTERVAL(WEEKDAY(transaction_date)) DAY)) AS `Week`
    FROM 
        shop_orders
    WHERE 1=1
        AND user_id = 123 
        AND transaction_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 WEEK
    GROUP BY 
        3
) t1 RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        DATE(DATE_SUB(transaction_date, INTERVAL(WEEKDAY(transaction_date)) DAY)) AS `Week`
    FROM 
        shop_orders 
    WHERE 
        transaction_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 12 WEEK 
    GROUP BY
        1
    ORDER BY
        1
) t2 USING (Week)
```

Comment: Note that nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN

Answer (score 0):

To return the weeks with no Orders you have to create a table with all the weeks.

For the order order by the same fields in the group by