# How to query for the first date of a week on the PREVIOUS year

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

Wracking my brain trying to figure this out, and I can't seem to find any existing threads that help.

Simply, I'd like to find the first day of the week (as a date) but one year ago, for any given date. Our calendar week starts on **Sunday**.

[Here's a snap of the table I have at my disposal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I89rd.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: So you [looked at the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) and found nothing? Keep poking, there's lots of good stuff on offer.

Comment: I did, though I'm rather new to SQL and date manipulations have never been my forté. Explanations below were helpful. Thanks anyways, sadman.

Comment: It's generally best to try something, *anything*, to show that you've tried rather than given up and just posted on Stack Overflow. We can often take your non-functional solution that last little distance without having to re-do all your work from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

See this.  [How do I get the first day of the week of a date in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944055/how-do-i-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-of-a-date-in-mysql)

You can get your required result this way:

```
mydate - INTERVAL 1 YEAR + INTERVAL 1-DAYOFWEEK(mydate - INTERVAL 1 YEAR) DAY
```

Explanation:

```
mydate - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

gives you the date a year before `mydate`.

```
anyday + INTERVAL 1-DAYOFWEEK(anyday) DAY
```

gives you the Sunday beginning the week of `anyday`.

Similarly you can get the first day of the month of `anyday` like this:

```
LAST_DAY(anyday) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Some people call this week- and month- *truncation*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `datesub()` to subtract one year from today (`curdate()`). Get the weekday with `weekday()`. It returns a number from `0` to `6` where `0` is Monday. Subtract that many days plus one, as your first weekday is Sunday not Monday.

```
date_sub(date_sub(curdate(),
                  INTERVAL 1 YEAR),
         INTERVAL weekday(date_sub(curdate(),
                                   INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) + 1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function to do it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `SUNDAY`(indate date) RETURNS date
    NO SQL
BEGIN
declare prevyear date;
set prevyear = indate - interval 1 year;
return prevyear - weekday(prevyear) - interval 1 day;
END
```