# MySQL: Extracting totals from last week and the week before last

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, sum

I am trying to get total view from the previous week and the week before last. I'll refer to these as WeekMinusOne and WeekMinusTwo respectively.

so for the present time, I would want views from the last FULL previous week i.e. 12/23 - 12/29 (I'd like to start my weeks on a Monday) and views from the WeekMinus two, i.e. 12.16-12.22.

While I know I can hard code this to the exact dates, I'd like it to autoupdate to reflect the new data. How can I do this?

format of the table i'm pulling from is simple.
just two columns,

```
date | # of unique views!
```

simplified look at my table

[image: simplified look at my table]

desired result

[image: desired result]

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. What are you *actually* using?

Comment: sorry i'm a little confused :( I'm new to sql, i'm using mysql

Comment: Add `CREATE TABLE` and sample data `INSERT INTO` into your question, and show desured result for this data. And specify MySLQL version.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: edited - please have a look

Answer (score 1):

To start with, consider the following expression:

```
current_date - interval (weekday(current_date)) day
```

It gives you the first day of the current week if your weeks start on Monday. As explained in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55335200/10676716), it your weeks start on Sunday, you need:

```
current_date - interval (dayofweek(current_date) - 1) day
```

Starting from there, we can filter the table on the 2 previous weeks and do conditional sums:

```
select 
    sum(
        case when view_date >= w.dt - interval 7 day then views else 0 end
    ) views_from_week_minus_one,
    sum(
        case when view_date < w.dt - interval 7 day then views else 0 end
    ) views_from_week_minus_two
from 
    views_table v
    inner join (select current_date - interval (weekday(current_date)) day dt) w
        on v.view_date >= w.dt - interval 14 day and and view_date < w.dt
```

An important thing is that, since it uses no date function on the date column, this query will benefit from an index on `views_table(view_date)`. Another advantage of the half-open interval strategy is that it would properly handle the time part of the date if any.

Answer (score -1):

Try next solution:

```
SELECT SUM(views) as total_views, WEEK(date, 1) AS week_num 
FROM your_table
WHERE WEEK(CURDATE(), 1) - WEEK(date, 1) < 2
GROUP BY week_num;
```

The query will return views summery grouped by week number