# Split Month by Week count using MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I have month start/end date i want to split that month into weeks where my week start from monday
forExample consider August 2023
that month week start from monday so date should be 31-july-2023 which will be start date of week-1
so on 31-july-2023 to 06-Aug-2023 should be consider as week-1
and 7-Aug-2023 to 13-Aug-2023 should be consider as week-2
and i want result in following format

| week_name | weekStartDate |
| --- | --- |
| week-1 | 31-07-2023 |
| week-2 | 07-08-2023 |
| week-3 | 14-08-2023 |
| week-4 | 21-08-2023 |
| week-5 | 28-08-2023 |

I want logic that if we pass any date it should return which week it belongs from that month week1,week2 or week3
using MySQL quires.
any solution for this ?
how we can achieve this in MySQL.

expected out should be

| week_name | weekStartDate |
| --- | --- |
| week-1 | 31-07-2023 |
| week-2 | 07-08-2023 |
| week-3 | 14-08-2023 |
| week-4 | 21-08-2023 |
| week-5 | 28-08-2023 |

month can be sept-2023, august-2023 any it should return correct result, any solution for this problem in MySQL

Comment: Use a `JOIN` with the condition `ON DAY(date) BETWEEN weekStartDate and DATE_ADD(weekStarDate, INTERVAL 6 DAY)`

Comment: Maybe this might be sufficient to answer your question? `DATE_ADD(mydate, INTERVAL(-WEEKDAY(mydate)) DAY);` https://stackoverflow.com/a/6944564/6055465

Comment: This can work but how to find week Number like week-1 or week-2 or week-3 in this