# How can I create a timestamp for the current year and week efficiently?

Tags: sql, mysql

Every time I search for this, the answer seems to be the following

```
WHERE WEEK(`timestamp_field`) = WEEK(CURDATE())
```

However, as pointed out in the comments for many of these (but sadly not providing an answer) won't this apply the WEEK() function to every single row first?

So it seems that it's much more efficient to search using a range for the timestamp field, but how can I determine which timestamps to use for the current week since I won't know which days to use?

Edit: I got it working with the following

```
WHERE `timestamp_field` > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY)
AND `timestamp_field` < CURDATE()
```

Comment: that should be efficent if you have an index on WEEK(`timestamp_field`), run `explain with multiple ìndexes and see which is taken and hiow fast it is

Comment: @nbk Can this really be optimized with an index? It can't be turned into a date comparison, because the week number repeats every year.

Comment: Is your condition actually `WHERE YEAR(timestamp_field) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND WEEK(`timestamp_field`) = WEEK(CURDATE())`? If not, it will be true for dates in the same week but other years.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6944055/how-do-i-get-the-first-day-of-the-week-of-a-date-in-mysql for how to get the date of the first day of the current week. Then you can use `timestamp_field BETWEEN @first_day AND DATE_ADD(@first_day, INTERVAL 1 WEEK)`

Comment: you can try  https://dbfiddle.uk/IBStRuCG  the generated column could be week or any other wanted

Comment: @nbk thanks but I got it working with this `WHERE timestamp_field > DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -WEEKDAY(CURDATE()) DAY) AND timestamp_field < CURDATE()`

Comment: still try my approach